# Jupyter Notebook Python error: return_type

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, montecarlo

I am getting an error regarding `return_type` so any help would be much appreciated :)

Code:

```
def daily_returns(data, days, iterations):
    ft = drift_calc(data, return_type='n')
    try:
        stv = log_returns(data).std().values
    except:
        stv = log_returns(data).std()
    dr = np.exp(ft + stv * norm.ppf(np.random.rand(days, iterations)))
    return dr

daily_returns(data, 50, 1000)
```

Error:

```
drift_calc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_type'
```

Comment: is drift_calc() your custom defined function? can you show us the code for that

Comment: Can you post or check the function definition of `drift_calc`. The error means the function definition of `drift_calc` is not expecting you to pass the argument `return_type`

Comment: @justanotherguy  that's the code: 
    def drift_calc(data):
    lr = log_returns(data)
    u = lr.mean()
    var = lr.var()
    drift = u-(0.5*var)
    try:
        return drift.values
    except:
        return drift
    
drift_calc(data)

Comment: as per the function definition, `drift_calc`  is only expecting a positional argument `data`.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful informaton.

Comment: better put code in question, not in comment. It will be more readable. And more people will see it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what the error message is telling you it is.  Your `drift_calc` function's signature is as follows, per your comment:

```
def drift_calc(data):
```

There is no parameter named `return_type` defined here.  So this line:

```
ft = drift_calc(data, return_type='n')
```

causes the error you're getting, because it is passing the named parameter `return_type` to the `drift_calc` function, which is not defined as taking such a parameter.